# PHP - How to show randomly posts on WP only for one category

Tags: php, wordpress

I need some help for the home page of a wordpress website.

The home page of the site show all the posts sorted by category. I'd like to display all the posts by date except for the category "À découvrir" (category name: decouvrir).

Here is the entire code of my page:

```html
   <?php get_header(); ?>
 
 <div class="container">
  
  <div id="content">

   <?php
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'orderby' => 'slug',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ) );
   ?>

   <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1 id="h1home">Visitez <strong>St-Cyprien,</strong><br> certainement le meilleur quartier de Toulouse.</h1>
    <h2 id="pres_home">Qu’ils soient commerçants ou habitants, à Saint-Cyprien, il n’y a que des voisins.<br/>
Ce quartier populaire a l’âme d’un faubourg et l’étoffe d’un village. Loin des guerres de clochers, il y règne comme une ambiance de marché. On y vit ou on y vient, on y sort ou on y dort car l’attractivité de Saint-Cyprien n’a d’égal que sa simplicité.<br/>
En d’autres termes, et sans prétention ni chauvinisme, il s’agit certainement du meilleur quartier de Toulouse.</h2>
   </div>
  
   <?php if(get_theme_mod( 'sp_featured_slider' ) == true) : ?>
    <?php get_template_part('inc/featured/featured'); ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  
   
  
   <div id="main" <?php if(get_theme_mod('sp_sidebar_homepage') == true) : ?>class="fullwidth"<?php endif; ?>>
    
    <ul class="sp-grid">
      <?php

       $tab_num = array(
        0 => array(
         'num' => 3,
         'template' => 'grid-trois'
        ),
        1 => array(
         'num' => 4,
         'template' => 'grid-quatre'
        ),
        2 => array(
         'num' => 6,
         'template' => 'grid-six'
        )
       );

       $i = 0;

       foreach( $categories as $category ) {


        if( ($category->count) >= 2 && $category->slug !== 'boutiques'){

         $category_link = sprintf( 
               '<a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s" class="link_tous">%3$s</a>',
               esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
               esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ),
               esc_html( 'Voir tous' )
           );
      ?>

      <div class="col-md-12">
       <h2 class="cat-name"><?php echo $category->name ?></h2>
       <?php echo sprintf( esc_html__( '%s', 'Voir tous' ), $category_link ); ?>
      </div>
       <ul class="sp-grid">


        <?php
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => $tab_num[$i][num], 'category_name' => $category->slug ) );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
         
         get_template_part('content', $tab_num[$i][template]);
        
        endwhile;
        endif;
        ?>
       </ul>
       
      <?php
       
        if($i < 2){
         $i++;
        }else{
         $i = 0;
        }
       }
      }
      ?>

    <!-- <div class="col-md-12"><h2>Actus</h2></div>
    <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'category_name' => 'actus' ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
     
     get_template_part('content', 'grid-trois');
    
    endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
    
    <div class="col-md-12"><h2>À découvrir</h2></div>
    <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'category_name' => 'decouvrir' ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
     
     get_template_part('content', 'grid-quatre');
    
    endwhile;
    endif;
    ?> -->

    <!-- C'est bientôt -->
     <!-- <div class="col-md-12"><h2>C'est bientôt</h2></div>
     <?php
     $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'category_name' => 'bientot' ) );
     if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
      
      get_template_part('content', 'grid-trois');
     
     endwhile;
     endif;
     ?> -->

    <!-- Patrimoine -->
     <!-- <div class="col-md-12"><h2>Patrimoine</h2></div>
     <ul class="sp-grid">
      <?php
      $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'category_name' => 'patrimoine' ) );
      if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
       $i = 1;
       get_template_part('content', 'grid-six');
      
      endwhile;
      endif;
      ?>
     </ul> -->
    <!-- FIN Patrimoine -->

    <!-- Restau -->
     <!-- <div class="col-md-12"><h2>Restaurants</h2></div>
     <?php
     $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'category_name' => 'restos' ) );
     if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
      
      get_template_part('content', 'grid-trois');
     
     endwhile;
     endif;
     ?> -->
    <!-- Fin restau -->

    <!-- Sorties -->
    <!--  <div class="col-md-12"><h2>Sorties</h2></div>
     <ul class="sp-grid">
      <?php
      $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'category_name' => 'sorties' ) );
      if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
       
       get_template_part('content', 'grid-quatre');
      
      endwhile;
      endif;
      ?>
     </ul> -->
    <!-- Fin Sorties -->
    

    <?php if(get_theme_mod( 'sp_promo' ) == true) : ?>
       <?php get_template_part('inc/promo/promo'); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php if(get_theme_mod('sp_home_layout') == 'grid' || get_theme_mod('sp_home_layout') == 'full_grid') : ?></ul><?php endif; ?>
    
     <!-- <?php solopine_pagination(); ?> -->
    



   
   </div>

<?php if(get_theme_mod('sp_sidebar_homepage')) : else : ?><?php get_sidebar(); ?><?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've tried to use a 'orderby' => 'rand' at line 37 and 104 but it doesn't do anything... I've also tried at line 70 but it display all the post randomly and not only for one category...

If you could just have a look and tell me what should i do it would be super!
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I suppose you're making a query to get the posts, can't you simply exclude this category from the query?

Comment: Hi Lucarnosky! Thanks for your answer. Yes that could be a good idea but i don't know how to do it...